# Как использовать стрелочные функции в объектах?

Tags: javascript

Могу ли я использовать стрелочные функции в объектах? Или в них нужно использовать обычные? Не совсем понял это из документации. И да, если можно, пример.

Comment: что имеется ввиду под _использовать стрелочные функции в объектах_?

Comment: @Grundy я имею ввиду arrow functions из нового стандарта,как я понимаю в объектах их нет смысла использовать потому что this для это window

Comment: объекты бывают разными. Приведи пример использования стрелочных функция в объекте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стрелочные функции привязаны к значению `this`. Так что всё как обычно.
Но они анонимные, поэтому метод сделать не получится, если вы об этом.

Answer (score 2):

Можете, но следует иметь ввиду, что [стрелочные функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) не имеют своего `this`, то есть следующие вызовы отработают по разному:

```
const name = 'Alisa';
const obj = {
  name: 'John',
  getArrowName: () => `Hello, ${this.name}`,
  getName: function() { return `Hello, ${this.name}`; };
};

obj.getArrowName(); //"Hello, Alisa"
obj.getName(); //"Hello, John"
```

`getName()` работает как надо. А при вызове `getArrowName()`, `this` будет ссылаться не на `obj`, а на окружающее лексическое окружение.

Их очень удобно использовать для функций-колбэков:

```
const options = {
  success: (response) => response,
  error: (xhr) =>throw new Error(xhr.status),
};

$.ajax(options);
```

Так же, возможно вам будет интересная "короткая запись методов" ([It's shorthand method names](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)), которая как и стрелочные функции, появилась в ES6, и которая ничем не отличается по смыслу от обычных методов.

```
var o = {
  property([parameters]) {},
};

// первый пример можно переписать так:
const obj = {
  name: 'John',
  getName() { return `Hello, ${this.name}`; };
};
```

Comment: я имел в виду то что для  метода объектов они(стрелочные функции) не подходят потому что obj.getArrowName(); выдаст "Hello, undefined"

Comment: Я ниже привел пример, как удобно использовать стрелочные функции в объектах - колбеки. Еще, если вы встречались с конструкцией `var self = this` или `var that = this`, то с помощью стрелочных функций можно от них просто избавиться. Так что использовать можно, только в нужных случаях :)

Comment: @saaaaaaaaasha спасибо большое за ответ лови плюсик