# стрелочные функции

Tags: javascript

При выводе на консоль, в **obj1** свойство **this.name** не отображается. Как правильно сделать привязку данных, подскажите? Во втором **obj2** использую стрелочную функцию, все отображается (стрелочные функции не имеют своего this). В третьем **obj3** ошибка

> Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Можно ли свойством объекта делать стрелочную функцию? Спасибо.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {

 let obj1 = {
  name: 'value',
  numbers: [1, 2, 3],
  fun1: function () {
   this.numbers.forEach(function (value, index, array) {
    console.log(this.name + ' ' + value);
   })
  }
 };

 obj1.fun1();

 let obj2 = {
  name: 'value',
  numbers: [4, 5, 6],
  fun1: function () {
   this.numbers.forEach((value, index, array) => {
    console.log(this.name + ' ' + value);
   })
  }
 };

 obj2.fun1();

 let obj3 = {
  name: 'value',
  numbers: [7, 8, 9],
  fun1: () => {
   this.numbers.forEach((value, index, array) => {
    console.log(this.name + ' ' + value);
   })
  }
 };

 obj3.fun1();

});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Такой же вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/587252/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85?rq=1) с подробным ответом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стрелочные функции не удастся использовать как методы, потому что они не захватывают контекст вызова.. Использование this в них, аналогично использованию this там, где они объявлены.
Чаще всего, вне 'strict mode' this ссылается на глобальный объект.

```js
window.data = 'Global data';
let test = {
  data: 'Object data',
  method() {
    console.log(this.data);
  },
  func: () => console.log(this.data)
}

test.method(); // Object data

test.func(); // Global data

let test2 = {
  data: 'Test2 data',
  method() {
    test.func2 = () => console.log(this.data);
  }
};

test2.method(); // в этом вызове this==test2
test.func2(); // Поэтому: Test2 data
```

---

В obj1 же, напротив. Функция обратного вызова forEach вызывается с пустым контекстом. Здесь как раз полезны стрелочные функции для доступа к внешнему this.
Разумеется, Вы вольны сохранить this любым другим способом:

```js
let obj1 = {
  name: 'value',
  numbers: [1, 2, 3],
  f1: function () {
   this.numbers.forEach((value, index, array) => {
    console.log(this.name, value, 'arrow');
   })
  },
  f2: function() {
   this.numbers.forEach(function(value, index, array){
    console.log(this.name, value, 'bind');
   }.bind(this))
  },
  f3: function() {
   let that = this;
   this.numbers.forEach(function(value, index, array){
    console.log(that.name, value, 'variable');
   });
  },
  f4: function() {
   this.numbers.forEach(function(value, index, array){
    console.log(this.name, value, 'forEach thisArg');
   }, this);
  }
 };
 
 obj1.f1();
 obj1.f2();
 obj1.f3();
 obj1.f4();
```

Comment: Уважаемый vp_arth! Спасибо Вам большое!

Comment: `forEach` вторым параметром принимает контекст для функции коллбэка

Comment: @Grundy, прикольно) Добавил четвёртый вариант..